# Would indexing increase the read performance in my case?

Tags: mongodb, indexing, mongodb-query

Actually I'm a complete beginner in `mongodb` so please do excuse me if my question is foolish or off-topic . Basically I'm storing user_information in a collection then I'm performing search operation by `fullname` field (it's not unique) . I've just read about indexing the `mongodb fields` to increase the performance . So, what I'm asking is ** Can or should I index the fullname field for getting faster result ?**

My Query for getting result in nodejs:

```
var regex = new RegExp(["^", string].join(""), "i");//string is received from user
db.collection("user_information").find({ fullname: regex },{_id:0}).toArray(function(err, result) {
if(err) throw err;
console.log(result);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, indexing would help you to increase the search operations. You can refer the documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer but sir , Can I index two or more fields of a collection?

Comment: Yes, you can create multiple indexes on multiple fields in a collection, alternatively, you can also have multiple fields defined in one index something like a compound index

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer sir